# Procedural hair deformation for rocks

Tags: modeling, particles

Using Cycles, I am trying to make a procedural rock hair particle system.  I have my ICO Sphere on another layer that has some random texture displacements.  However, I want to apply a random deform to the overall shape of the rock, is this possible?  Hair length doesn't really do it.  Is  it maybe possible to put an empty in the main scene that would affect the hair shape?

Comment: Hi. Please edit your question and explain in more detail what it is that you are trying to do. Are there maybe pictures that could illustrate the result you are after? Could you also post some screenshots of what you have tried to do and explain how that turns out different from your goals or expectations? I am afraid, at the moment it is hard to understand what you are asking.

Comment: Hmm.. I'm sorry for not providing some more context.  I think I found a solution though. I just made 5 different rocks on the different layer and loaded them into my main layer's scene for the hair particles as a group of objects.  Now I can add random adjustments to the hair or 'rock' particles). This allowed me to perform some Simple Deforms with empties on each rock 'particle'. I just wanted to deform my rocks so I don't have a bunch of randomly displacement mapped rocks that were only perfect spheres if that makes sense, lol. You answer all the questions on here! So I appreciate your time!

Comment: I am going to leave the close vote for now, but if you found the time for it you could probably edit the question to make it a bit clearer and provide the answer yourself for others who might have a similar problem to find.

Comment: @Ryan You should post that as an answer below, with a short description of the procedure, maybe a few images showing the result.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I can't post any images right now.  However, it's pretty basic what I did, so let me explain real quick.  I actually got the general idea from a great YouTube tutorial author that I watch, Sardi Pax.

I have a scene with a plane for the ground.  I put a hair particle system all across the plane.  I then went to another layer and created five ICOSphere "rocks" and applied a Noise and the Voronoi textures used for displacement mappings(set the material's settings section tab displacement flag to true after enabling "Experimental").  Then I tweaked these displacements to make the rocks look different.  I also applied a simple deform modifier with an empty to each rock to get unique shapes for them.  Then I Object grouped(CTRL+G) the rocks on that separate layer together.  Then I went back to my original layer with the plane and then used the rocks group as the hair particle system's display property.  I also created vertex groups on my plane(randomly selected).  Then I applied the rocks(with pick random from group selection in the particle's properties, so it would pick random rocks for me from the rock object group) to the plane's vertex groups that I created.  And since I put the rocks at 0 on the Z-axis on the other layer the rocks look buried in the plane's "dirt", pretty neat.   This gave me a decent spread across the plane of random rocks that didn't appear to be too repetitious.  I hope this makes sense, I'll try to post images later.